# How do I can set custom message for errorThrown parameter in ajax error callback?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, .net-core, http-status-codes

I have an actionfilter in my dotnet core application and want to generate a proper message for user when ajax call return error result.

In client side **errorThrown** parameter display to user and I don't want change client side scripts.

When ajax call has exception (500 status code), user got just "Internal Server Error" message, I'm going to display more detailed information.

I tried using `return StatusCode(500, Json("Custom error"))`, `return StatusCode(500, "Custom error")` but no deference in result that showing to user.

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $('#failed-info').text(errorThrown);
}
```

The best solution for me is that I can provide a custom statusCode and statusText result, for example statusCode = 700, StatusText = "It 's not allowed for security reasons."

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand. You want to change the code on the API server side?

Comment: Is your error function being triggered at all by the 500 status code? Also, what is the code on your actionfilter?

Answer (score 0):

WEB API Server side sample of custom message

```cs
    public class MyAPIController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("~/api/mypath/")]
        public IHttpActionResult returnError([FromBody]StringModel value)
        {

           return Content(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,"bla bla bla");

        }
    }
```

In the example it returns status `Forbidden (403)` but you can change to what you want.

But the browser depending on the status may override the error.

Comment: Thanks for your attention, but I'm develop on dotnet core 2.2 which there is no `IHttpActionResult` and especially `Content` function with status code parameter.